# Unable to set checkbox checked on MVC page load

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

In my MVC view, I have a dynamically created list of checkboxes.

```
@foreach (var door in Model.Doors)
{
    <input type="checkbox" id="@door.ID" name="DoorIds" value="door.ID"/>@Html.Label(door.DoorName);
}
```

My model -

```
public virtual IList<int> assignedDoors { get; set; }
public int[] DoorIds { get; set; }
```

When I tick some checkboxes and press Save, the changes are committed to the database. However, I can't seem to work out how to check the required boxes on page load?

If I put the below code in the HTML checkbox line,

```
checked="@Model.assignedDoors.Contains(@door.ID)" }
```

the checkboxes are checked, but when I press Save, I get the following error -

> The value 'door.ID,door.ID' is not valid for DoorIds.

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: you need an @ before door.ID, so it should be value="@door.ID"

Comment: `checked="@Model.assignedDoors.Contains(@door.ID)"` makes the checkbox checked whatever the value of `door.ID` is (and its invalid html). See Omu's solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there's 2 prolems

first `value="door.ID"` you forgot the `@` before `door.ID`

and second, this code:

```
checked="@Model.assignedDoors.Contains(@door.ID)"
```

will make the checkboxes always checked, instead you need to do something like this:
example here: http://jsbin.com/xonaxaqigi/1/edit

```
@(Model.assignedDoors.Contains(door.ID) ? "checked='checked'": "")
```

so you need complete absence of the checked attribute or `checked='checked'`

Comment: Depending on the version of MVC you may be able to have your conditional just for the value of the checked attribute and return null if the assignedDoors collection doesn't contain the door ID (which doesn't need an "@" symbol as you are already in code context?). As of MVC 4 returning null as an attribute value won't render the attribute when using the Razor view engine.

Comment: removed the "@", guess that would be another problem, Contains returns bool so null shouldn't be not possible

Comment: I meant use Contains for the inline conditional within the value and return either empty string or "checked" for true, and null for false.